# What is the model attached to django UserCreationForm()

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I have read the official documentation for UserCreationForm(). I am trying to access the users I have created within other models. What model do I call to access the users I created within the UserCreationForm()? In short is their a default authentication model I can call to access the user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What model do I call to access the users I created within the `UserCreationForm()`?

As we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L82-L139), it uses the `User` model:

> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>
> # …
>
> class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
>
>     # …
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = User
>         fields = ("username",)
>         field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}
>
>     # …
> ```

You thus can import this model with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

The [documentation on the **`User`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) specifies the fields and methods defined on this model.